# Insert node in Min Heap prioritizing left child

Tags: c, heap

After getting the code for inserting a note in a Min Heap right, I'm confused when it comes to what changes should I make if I want to prioritize the left child of a node when rearranging the heap.
The input would be something like:

```
I 5 //insert number 5 in the Min Heap
I 4
I 3
I 2
I 1
```

and the output should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

instead of the usual:

```
1 2 4 5 3
```

Any ideas on how to get to this output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get the code for removing something from the heap correct, too? What makes the order 1,2,4,5,3 "usual"? What order is it? The order you get when you always remove the minimal element from the heap?

Comment: This is a rather odd requirement. Why do you think you need your heap to be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the heap depends entirely on the order in which you insert items. The reason is that, when inserting, you add the new node to the end of the heap and then sift it up through its parent's pointer. The rules are:

1. Add the item to the end of the heap.
2. If the item is greater than or equal to its parent, then done.
3. Swap the item with its parent.
4. Go to 2.

Given those rules, let's walk through what happens when you insert items in the order `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

```
[5]
[5,4] // the new item is smaller than its parent, so swap
[4,5]
[4,5,3] // the new item is smaller than its parent, so swap
[3,5,4]
[3,5,4,2] // the new item is smaller than its parent, so swap
[3,2,4,5] // still smaller than its parent
[2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5,1] // 1 is smaller than 3, so swap
[2,1,4,5,3] // 1 is smaller than 2, so swap
[1,2,4,5,3]
```

There's no efficient way to "prioritize" a particular subtree, especially in a binary heap. It looks simple enough in a heap with just five items, but every level you add increases the cost of keeping sibling nodes in the proper order. You're better off just sorting the nodes and creating a heap from the resulting array.

Not that a sorted heap helps you much. As soon as you removed the first item, rearranging the heap would cause it to no longer be sorted.